# How can I unbind an eventhandler from Marionette in another js file?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, jquery-events, unbind

This is my file file1.js

```
//more code

Test.Views.TestTab = Marionette.Layout.extend({
  template: JST["templates/test/myfile"],
  className: "activity-contents",
  events: {
    "focus textarea" : "event2"
  }
  //more code

  event2: function(event) {
    alert("test");
   //do something
  },
  //more code
});
//more code
```

In another file I need to do something different with the focus event in textarea, but the alert always happened, I can't change the code in file1.js, In file2.js a file without Marionette, only with Jquery I tried with the following options, but this failed, any idea?

```
 jQuery('textarea').off('focus');
 jQuery('textarea').off();
 jQuery('textarea').unbind('focus');
 jQuery('textarea').unbind();
```

Comment: does file1 also instantiate the views?

Comment: This is made in another file, I only can modify the file2.js in my plugin, can I unbind the focus action "event2" and put another action for example a console.log("alert")?

Comment: It's interesting that you use events on a `layout`, I never had that idea as I saw layouts to be ... well, layouts ;) I bind events in (item/collection/composite-)views. Maybe move your focus event down to the views you use in this layout (look at the new `behavior` stuff for reuse), then you will have an easier time to override `focus` in other views later.

Comment: I can not modify file1.js and file1.js is not my code, my code is in file2.js and this is a file without Marionnete,is just JQuery